# Get background color to fill full height of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has fixed height and a background color - as you can imagine the background color does not expand to fill the full height of the div.

I also have 4 `div`s within this container div for rounded corners. I have included the code below. How do I get the background color to extend to the bottom of the container div regardless of content?

```css
    #art2 {
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      float: right;
      width: 485px;
      background-color: #262626;
    }
    .art2boxtl {
      background-image: url(../images/tlar2.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 10px;
      width: 9px;
    }
    .art2boxtr {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 15px;
      background-image: url(../images/trar2.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 10px;
      width: 9px;
    }
    .art2boxbl {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      background-image: url(../images/blar2.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 11px;
      width: 10px;
    }
    .art2boxbr {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 10px;
      background-image: url(../images/brar2.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 11px;
      width: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="art2">
  <div class="art2boxtl"></div>
  <div class="art2boxtr"></div>
  CONTENT
  <div class="art2boxbl"></div>
  <div class="art2boxbr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOur problem is not the `background-color` - that will fill the whole area just fine - but the fact that the surrounding DIV is not stretching to the full size of all the DIVs inside it.

Raveren's approach will stretch the parent div if the childrens are `float: right` or `float: left`. It won't work for the `position:absolute` ones. For those, you will have to give the parent container a fixed height.

Answer (score 2):

Try something among the lines of:

```
          <div id="art2">
              <div class="art2boxtl"></div>
              <div class="art2boxtr"></div>
              CONTENT
              <div class="art2boxbl"></div>
              <div class="art2boxbr"></div>
              <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>
```

note the `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Comment: Won't work in this case, his containing elements are `position: absolute`. It would be the right approach if the elements where `float: left` or `right`

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute` for you parent div.
This solved the problem for me.

You can also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968401/6751430