# Background color does not show when setting a div height to auto! Why?

Tags: css, html, height

The background-color of #container does not show when I set its height to auto. But it does show when I set it to a fixed height like 1000px. I've tried "overflow:auto", but it didn't work. How can I fix it? I do want #container to vertically expand according to its content and I want to show its background color as well. Any idea will be much appreciated!

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="div1">text text text text text text text text text text text texttexttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
        <div id="div2">text text text text text text text text text text text texttexttext</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--end of main-->
</div><!--end of container-->
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 204);
    height: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
}
#container #main {
    background-color: rgb(204, 51, 0);
    height: auto;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container #main #div1 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
}
#container #main #div2 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 153, 153);
    height: auto;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem you have is that `#main div` have `position:absolute;`. You have to take on account that element with `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` are removed from normal flow, so they basicly are not inside their parent.

[here is your code running](http://embed.plnkr.co/2mLfiuvWWLcasPqAXhvY/preview)

for more details on that you can check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

hope that helps

Comment: don't link to w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/. MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is much better; for positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: w3schools explains it well, MDN is better for reference and it have more up to date info

Answer (score 2):

All of you elements are either positioned absolutely or floated, that won't compute a height for the parent. Try setting a min-height on some of your elements or atleast on the container.

Give me a moment and I'll try to set up a jsfiddle with a solution :)

!!! See lazychio's answer, its what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

simply add overflow:auto; in .css file for example:

```
#products_box{
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:pink;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```